# Angular 6 Model and Rest request format bridge

Tags: angular, rest, mapping, response

Angular app is connected to a REST Api. Now for example, rest api responds with `User` object like:

```
{
    first_name: 'Super',
    last_name: 'Admin'
}
```

In Angular section, `User` model is like following:

```
export class User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Now, when I getting data from service how can I map response object to angular model? As the names are different (it could be more complex situation), how `firstName` will represent `first_name`?

This situation also appears for sending request to api as request parameters are `first_name` and `last_name`.

It can be done by mapping each field separately or creating UserForm object. But is there any way to use transformer which can map the api fields to model object and vice versa?

Comment: Use the `.map` function of `Observable`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would prefer to add `propertyParamMap` object inside the service, which will be used before sending any request to the Api or after receiving the response from api.

service.ts - from where api requests are sent.

```
class MyService{
  private propertParamMap = {};    

     constructor() {
       this.propertyParamMap = {
            'id': 'id',
            'firstName': 'first_name',
            'lastName': 'last_name',
        };
    }
}
```

example code - can be optimized better

```
post (data) {
    // map before sending request
    data = data.map((item) => this.propertyParamMap[item])
   this.http.post(data).pipe(
           map((resp) => { 
                // map after receiving response
                let modelData = {}                    
                for (let keyProperty in this.propertyParamMap) {        
                 // loop through propertyParamMap array
                    if (this.propertyParamMap[keyProperty] in resp) {      
                    // check if value exist within response object
                        modelData[keyProperty] = resp[this.propertyParamMap[keyProperty]];
                    }
                }
          });                 
}
```